# Ruby Command line calculator

Tags: ruby, command-line, calculator

I'm trying to make a command line calculator, but I have no idea where to start.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    puts "Calculator "
    puts "please write what youd like to calculate . i.e '4 + 3 * 4'"

    cal = gets.chomp.split(" ")

    cal.map!.with_index do |num, i|
      if i.even?
        num.to_i
      else
        num.to_sym
      end
    end
    cal.inspect 
    # i.e [3, :+, 4]
```

I want to be able to get what's inside the array and return the result of it. Like this: `3 + 4 = 7`

Answer (score 3):

For a simple calculator, you'll likely want to check the locations of the symbols in **BODMAS** order first.

Keeping it simple, change that to **DMAS - division, multiplication, addition and then subtraction.**

Let's take `"4 + 3 - 5 / 2 * 5"`. Making the assumption that you have in thinking the user will separate each symbol or number with a space, we can split this string up by spaces.

Additionally, assuming the user entered a correct (not erroneous) calculation, we should look for the index of the first operator to act on. Due to DMAS, we should do division first.

We find the index of the `/` and then divide the value in the index before that with the value in the index after that, so `5 / 2`.

In the array, replace the values you just used and the operator with the value you calculated. So, `["4", "+", "3", "-", "5", "/", "2", "*", "5"]` becomes `[4, "+", 3, "-", 2.5, "*", 5]`.

You then repeat this process, changing what you do with the values depending on what the operator is.

Comment: Does this approach work indeed?

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there!

As you're perhaps aware, operators like `+` are just syntactic sugar for methods in Ruby, so this array:

```
cal = [3, :+, 4]
```

...has everything you need: a receiver (`3`), a method to call on that receiver (`:+`), and an argument (`4`):

```
recv, meth, arg = cal
recv.public_send(meth, arg)
# => 7
```

The above is equivalent to calling `3.+(4)`, which is of course the same as `3 + 4`.

Comment: What do you propose when you encounter a need for parentheses for prioritization?  3 * 5 + 2 != 3 * (5 + 2)

Comment: Solve expressions inside parentheses first and replace them with the result. Do so recursively until you have a single result.

Comment: It’s worth to mention/refer that `[3, :+, 4]` is called [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) and there are languages (like e. g. LISP) that use AST as the language syntax itself. Unfortunately, building complete AST in ruby is painful process, since ruby was not designed to be transparent against it’s AST (unlike e. g. Elixir.)

Answer (score 2):

Use eval on the input string from the user and it should handle that for you. I. e.:

```
eval('4 + 3 * 4')
#⇒ 16
```

You can run this in irb if you want to see different quick examples of eval handling different strings.

Here is a post about using eval.

https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/5-metaprogramming-ruby-ascent/chapters/24-eval/lessons/63-eval

Comment: it works thanks . so this basically replaces moslty all that ive written lol

Comment: I would recommend against this. `eval` is not something you want to get in the habit of using; it's dangerous because ruby will run any code that you enter. For an app that only you will be using, it will probably be fine, but in general you could write a harmless calculator app, and a user could enter, for example, `\`cd ~; rm -r\``, and your app would go ahead and delete the home directory.

Comment: @lwassink from the fact that _the user was able to run calculator, and the process, executing calculator, was able to execute the command_, immediately follows that this user was able just to run the command herself. On the other hand, when somebody is programming a calculator, it is likely a studying process and that’s why I would not recommend to just use `eval`, which works pretty fine in many cases and which is unfair claimed to be dangerous in 90% of cases. Eval should be used with precaution—yes, but it is a perfect tool in hands of a good programmer.